# StackDriver Debug "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Service account not enabled on this instance"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

I am using GCP VM to host a few ecommerce websites via Cloud DNS 
I am trying to set up Stackdriver Debug (PHP) on my GCP VM for one of ecommerces websites.

I managed to follow through the steps successfully till Step #4.
[Setting Up Stackdriver Debugger for PHP > Compute Engine > Step #4](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/php#gce)

But when running the below code:

```
php /home/"my-domain"/public_html/vendor/bin/google-cloud-debugger -s /home/"my-domain"/public_html
```

I am getting an error as below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\NotFoundException: 
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":
    "Service account not enabled on this instance"} in /home/"my-domain"/public_html/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:263
```

I have opened for all Google APIs and enabled and I have created API key and OAuth 2.0 client IDs (not sure if this is needed tho). I am not sure what's missing here. Anyone has any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This error is indicative that your VM does not have a service account. Please go to [Menu>Compute Engine>click on your VM] and check if that is the case.